# How to access node attributes without key in networkx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, networkx

please i need help for this :

I need to access node attribute without key :

I have this code :

```
csv_F = csv.reader(open("MyFile.txt"),delimiter = '/')

for line in csv_F:    
    node = line[0]    
    attribute = line[1:] # there's no key to specify attribute   
    G.add_node(line[0], 'myattibute' = attribute)
```

How can i get all node attribute now ? for every node in the graph G without key?

i tried this and didnt work :

```
for nodex in G.nodes(data=True):  
    for b in (nodex[1]):
        print(b, " --- ")
```

and it return only

```
'myattribute ---'   
'myattribute ---'

...
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: can you provide some idea of what `myfile.txt` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Your trouble is here:

```
for nodex in G.nodes(data=True):  
    for b in (nodex[1]):
        print(b, " --- ")
```

`nodex[1]` is a dict containing all the attributes.  When you iterate `for b in D:` where `D` is a dict you're iterating over the keys.  So in your case you're printing out the key `b` (which is `'myattribute'`), but I suspect you want `nodex[1][b]`, which is the value.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Joel, i solved the problem with your help :)