# How to access node attributes without using keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, networkx

Im working on Networkx, and i want to know if its possible to access a node attributes without keys ?

I have a graph G, and node contains many attributes, and i just want to change them randomly over time, so is it possible to get them without key ? thank you.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you plan to do with it?  I do not understand what you're asking for, so seeing what you plan to do might help answer the question.  Short answer though - no.  To get the height or weight (or whatever) of a node, you'll have to tell networkx you want the height or weight (or whatever)

Comment: Please could you check this link : i posted my problem with my solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50063930/how-to-access-node-attributes-without-key-in-networkx

Comment: As Joel said, it isn't obvious what you are trying to do; the other question doesn't clarify this one (at least for me).  I have one guess that might make sense: do you want to make updates to a random attribute of a random node at each timestep/interval? And you don't want to specify ahead of time which attribute to change?  That is solvable -- but I won't add an answer if it isn't what you want to do..